# Configure fk relations with computed columns Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, code-first

I have a DB-model where there are computed columns. Basic idea is that when I insert a new `Gauge` into the table, a new `Reading` is automatically inserted into another table first. The table `Gauges` has a computed column (or several to be exact), that fetches the date of the latest `Reading`.

This all worked fine when I had a `INT` field that was used as a foreign key. Now the scope is growing so much that I can't rely on that field being unique anymore, so I needed to change the FK.

First I tried using the `Gauge.Id` property, which would be ideal, since that's the primary key in the table. Problem is that the `Id` is generated at the database, so it's not known when the first `Reading` is inserted. Also tried adding another `Guid` property to the model and using that as a FK, also didn't get it working. I have also tried checking the largest `Id` value from the DB before inserting, and assigning it to the new `Gauge` when creating, with no luck there either. Unfortunately I can't remember all the trial-and-error combinations to better clarify the problems on each try.

I'm using Entity Framework 6 code-first.

Object model is:

```
public class Gauge
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CurrentReadingDate { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public decimal CurrentReading { get; set; }
}

public class GaugeReading
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GaugeId { get; set; }
}
```

Database:

```
[dbo].[Gauges]
[Id]                    INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CurrentReadingDate]    AS               ([dbo].[CurrentReadingDate]([Id])),
[CurrentReading]        AS               ([dbo].[CurrentReading]([Id]))

[dbo].[GaugeReadings]
[Id]          INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[GaugeId]     INT              NOT NULL,
[ReadingDate] DATETIME         NOT NULL,
[Reading]     DECIMAL (18, 2)  NOT NULL,
```

Functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CurrentReadingDate]
(
    @id int
)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT MAX(GaugeReadings.ReadingDate) 
            FROM GaugeReadings 
            WHERE dbo.GaugeReadings.GaugeId = @id)
END
```

**The question is:** How to configure Entity Framework (and the database) to be able to insert a `Gauge` with an initial `Reading` so that the computed columns work? Or is there maybe a different insert method in the EF that would allow something like this? Sorry for the verbose question.

**Edit** The error I'm getting while using `Gauge.Id` as FK:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: A null store-generated value
>   was returned for a non-nullable member 'CurrentReadingDate' of type
>   'Repository.Gauge'.

Comment: I think the problem is in your function. check if no row exists in table, return some default date that is the minimum date allowed by db

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan Unbelieveable. Thanks! So it was. Null-checking all the functions did the trick! I was looking at the problem all wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your function. check if no row exists in table, return some default date that is the minimum date allowed by db.